# Nothing appears whenever the input is Female and married but there is an output if the input is Female an single

Tags: php

I am a PHP noob and I need help.

Nothing appears whenever the input is `Female` and `married` but there is an output if the input is `Female` and `single`. I am having a hard time figuring it out.

Here is the code:

```
if($gender =="Female" And $status=="married"){      
    $output.= " <b>  Your Fullname: </b>  Mrs.  " .$fname.    "    "  .$mname.   "   " .$lname.   "</br>" ;
}

else{
    if($gender =="Female" And $status =="single"){      
        $output.= " <b>  Your Fullname: </b> Ms.  " .$fname.    "    "  .$mname.   "   " .$lname.   "</br>" ;
    } else{
        $output.= " <b>  Your Fullname: </b>  Mr. " .$fname.    "    "  .$mname.   "   " .$lname.   "</br>" ;
    }
}
```

Comment: replace `And` with `&&`

Comment: What is your output? `Your Fullname: Mr. ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would need to know what `$gender` and `$status` resolve to to really know what condition you're supposed to be getting.

You could condense this down to a ternary operator...

```
$output.= " <b>  Your Fullname: </b>  ". $gender == 'Female' ? ($status == 'married' ? 'Mrs.' : 'Ms.') : 'Mr.' ."  " .$fname.    "    "  .$mname.   "   " .$lname.   "</br>" ;
```

Or preprocess their designation...

```
$prefix = 'Mr.';
if($gender == 'Female')
{
    if($status == 'married')
    {
        $prefix = 'Mrs.';
    }
    else
    {
        $prefix = 'Ms.';
    }
}

$output.= " <b>  Your Fullname: </b>  " .$prefix. "  " .$fname.    "    "  .$mname.   "   " .$lname.   "</br>" ;
```

While `and` may serve as `&&` technically you may want to stick to conventions. `&&` will be the most common syntax. My initial suspicion is that $status never actually == 'married'.